# How can i match values inside the same dataframe?

Tags: r, data-science

My dataframe looks like the following:

```
  destination origen iso3_exp Importer    flow      iso3_imp    gdp_o      gdp_d      distw  año
1    ABW    AUT       40      533    188.782      ABW 240457629696 1320670336  8632.9708 1995
2    AUT    ABW       58      533    912.362      ABW 289122615296 1320670336  7843.2555 1995
3    CHL    ARG       76      533   4535.649      ABW 768951320576 1320670336  4431.5712 1995
4    ARG    CHL      156      533    496.458      ABW 728007573504 1320670336 14590.9239 1995
5    AUT    BEL      170      533 116442.845      ABW  92507275264 1320670336   929.5887 1995
```

I need to create a variable called totalflow that is the sum the variable "flow" between the rows that matches Origen-Destination, for example: the row 3 has Destination to CHL and Origen from ARG, and the row 4 has the destination to ARG and origen from CHL i need tu sum the flow of that row (3) with the flow of the row 4 and do the same to all the other rows.

```
  destination origen iso3_exp Importer    flow      iso3_imp    gdp_o      gdp_d  distw  año   totalflow
1    ABW    AUT       40      533      188.782      ABW 240457629696 1320670336  8632.9708 1995  1100
2    AUT    ABW       58      533      912.362      ABW 289122615296 1320670336  7843.2555 1995  1100
3    CHL    ARG       76      533     4535.649      ABW 768951320576 1320670336  4431.5712 1995  5031
4    ARG    CHL      156      533      496.458      ABW 728007573504 1320670336 14590.9239 1995  5031
5    AUT    BEL      170      533   116442.845      ABW  92507275264 1320670336   929.5887 1995 116442
```

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a group column that has sorted origin and destination values.

```
df$group <- with(df,paste0(pmax(destination, origen),pmin(destination, origen)))
```

Once you have that you can group by `group` column and calculate `sum` of `flow`.

```
#Base R
df$totalflow <- with(df, ave(flow, group, FUN = sum))

#dplyr
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(total_flow  =sum(flow))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, totalflow := sum(flow), group]
```

This returns :

```
df
#  destination origen iso3_exp Importer       flow iso3_imp        gdp_o
#1         ABW    AUT       40      533    188.782      ABW 240457629696
#2         AUT    ABW       58      533    912.362      ABW 289122615296
#3         CHL    ARG       76      533   4535.649      ABW 768951320576
#4         ARG    CHL      156      533    496.458      ABW 728007573504
#5         AUT    BEL      170      533 116442.845      ABW  92507275264

#       gdp_d      distw  año  group  totalflow
#1 1320670336  8632.9708 1995 AUTABW   1101.144
#2 1320670336  7843.2555 1995 AUTABW   1101.144
#3 1320670336  4431.5712 1995 CHLARG   5032.107
#4 1320670336 14590.9239 1995 CHLARG   5032.107
#5 1320670336   929.5887 1995 BELAUT 116442.845
```

You remove the `group` column if it is not needed by `df$group <- NULL`.